# Remove element out of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple in moy code:

```
('H', 'NNP')
```

This is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import pos_tag
import nltk
syno =[]


sentence = '''His father suggested he study to become a parson instead, but Darwin was far more inclined to study natural history.DarwinDar·win (där'wĭn),Charles Robert.1809-1882.British naturalist who revolutionized the study of biology with his theory ofevolutionbased on natural selection
Like several scientists before him, Darwin believed all the life on earth evolved (developed gradually) over millions of years from a few common ancestors.'''
sent = pos_tag(sentence)

alpha = [s for s in sent if s[1] == 'NNP']
for i in range(0,len(alpha)-1):
    print alpha[i] #return the tuple
```

I want to remove only H from this. How can i do so?

Comment: You cannot modify tuples. You can only extract the data you need and create a new tuple.

Comment: As already others have pointed out: If you need tuples to mutate, you should use lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, so you will have to make a new one:

```
>>> t = ('H', 'NNP')
>>> tuple(x for x in t if x != 'H')
('NNP',)
>>> z = tuple(x for x in t if x == 'H')
>>> z
('H',)
>>> z[0]
'H'
>>>
```

Comment: No can i just extract the 'H' and put it in a different variable.

Comment: @user2675742 - Yes, see my edit.  Once again though, you need to make a new tuple because tuples are immutable.

Comment: Well i see you made x== 'H'. But what if i don't know what the value of that is. Can i just pick the first element out of the tuple?

Comment: Sure.  Just index it at 0.  `('H', 'NNP')[0]` yields `'H'`.

Comment: `z = t[t.index('H')]` is kind of pointless. `z = 'H'` would be easier in that case ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - Very good point.  Don't know what I was thinking.  I've used Python forever and yet I still suffer the occasional brainlock. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change tuples, they are "immutable"

If you instead use a mutable data structure like a list you can change them

```
>>>a = ['H', 'NNP']
>>>a[0] = 'J'          # this changes the 'H' to a 'J'
>>>print a
['J', 'NNP']
```

if you needed to convert one to the other for some reason you could do `myTuple = tuple(myList)` or `myList = list(myTuple)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = ('H', 'NNP')
>>> x = tuple(list(x)[1:])
>>> x
('NNP',)
```